# How to make page auto scroll when page expands? (Collapsible content)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im making a little project, and I have added 4 collapsible text boxes under everything else. The problem is, when I open content1 it expands and pushes content2-4 under, and I'm trying to get it to automatically scroll down so the user doesn't have to manually scroll to see the rest of the collapsible boxes. They are both in div containers, and I'm not too experienced with viewpoint and what not, and not sure how to use scrollintoview or where to put it.

```
In HTML

<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">

<button class="collapsible">Text 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Text 2</button>
<div class="content1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Text 3</button>
<div class="content2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Text 4</button>
<div class="content3">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Text 5</button>
<div class="content4">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

In Css:
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #005a32;
}
.content1 {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content2 {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #005a32;
}

.content3 {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content4 {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #005a32;
}``
``
```

Comment: you need to provide some code if you want to get help. Also , take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

### Use scrollIntoView

Catch the element and then

`element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "auto", block: "end" })`

Active this on the element who wrap the text boxes.

Active it when you get trigger open/expand/push

Comment: What do you mean by catch the element? I'm a newbie to all of this and Ive been taking online courses to learn html css js but I'm not exactly sure what you're implying.

Comment: oh nice, ok I mean use something like `document.getElementById(id)`
(https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)
here is the link for w3schools example and explain.
In shore you can set id to div like `<div id="abc">The boxes</div>` and do document.getElementById(id) => document.getElementById(abc).
`var list = document.getElementById(abc);` and then `list..scrollIntoView({ behavior: "auto", block: "end" })`.
I hope it will work